# How to query container memory limit in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I am using Prometheus tool for monitoring my Kubernetes cluster.

I have set a resource limit(memory limit) in my deployments and need to configure a panel for showing the total  memory available. Please let me know the query needed to run in Prometheus for getting the total memory limit available for my deployment.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using metrics kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes (provided by [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics)) and container_memory_usage_bytes (provided by kubelet/cAdvisor)

```
label_replace(
  label_replace(
    kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes{},
    "pod_name", 
    "$1", 
    "pod", 
    "(.+)"
  ),
  "container_name", 
  "$1", 
  "container", 
  "(.+)"
) 
-
on(pod_name,namespace,container_name) 
avg(
      container_memory_usage_bytes{pod_name=~".+"}
)
by (pod_name,namespace,container_name)
```

A little explanation of the query: It is a subtraction of the memory limit and the actual usage. `label_replace` functions are needed to match the label names of both metrics, as they are obtained from different targets. `avg` is used to get the average between pod restarts, as every pod restart creates a new metric. `{pod_name=~".+"}` is used to filter metrics from `container_memory_usage_bytes` that are not useful for this case

Comment: What would be the best way to turn this into an alert for if a container's memory usage goes over the limit?  Use a less-than operator instead of subtraction?

Answer (score 1):

The following PromQL query returns per-container free memory starting from Kubernetes v1.16:

```
kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="memory"}
  - on(namespace, pod, container)
container_memory_usage_bytes
```

The `on()` modifier instructs Prometheus to take into account only the listed labels when finding pairs of time series with identical labels on the left and the right side of `-`  operator. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) for details.