# container_memory_usage_bytes by deployment name

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics

Given a kubernetes cluster with:

1. [prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus)
2. [node-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter)
3. [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics)

I like to use the metric `container_memory_usage_bytes` but select by `deployment_name` instead of `pod`.

Selectors like `container_memory_usage_bytes{pod_name=~"foo-.+"}` if the `deployment_name=foo` are great as long there is not a deployment with `deployment_name=foo-bar`.

The same I'd like to achieve with the metric `kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Hello, please tell if have you checked this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52588387/12257134?

Comment: I was not able to solve my issue "just" with this task, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**There is no straightforward way to query prometheus by a `deployment-name`.**

You can query memory usage of a specific deployment by using deployment's labels.

Used query:

```
sum(
  kube_pod_labels{label_app=~"ubuntu.*"} * on (pod) group_right(label_app) container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="memory-testing", container=""}
  ) 
  by (label_app)
```

There is an awesome article which explains the concepts behind this query. I encourage you to read it:

- *[Medium.com: Amimahloof: Kubernetes promql prometheus cpu aggregation walkthrough](https://medium.com/@amimahloof/kubernetes-promql-prometheus-cpu-aggregation-walkthrough-2c6fd2f941eb)*

I've included an explanation with example below.

---

The selector mentioned in the question:
`container_memory_usage_bytes{pod_name=~"foo-.+"}`

> `.+` - match any string but not an empty string

with pods like:

- `foo-12345678-abcde` - **will match** (deployment `foo`)
- `foo-deployment-98765432-zyxzy` - **will match** (deployment `foo-deployment`)

As shown above it will match for both pods and for both deployments.

For more reference:

- *[Prometheus.io: Docs: Prometheus: Querying: Basics](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/)*

---

As mentioned earlier, you can use labels from your deployment to pinpoint the resource used by your specific deployment.

Assuming that:

- There are 2 deployments in `memory-testing` namespace:

  - `ubuntu` with 3 replicas
  - `ubuntu-additional` with 3 replicas
- Above deployments have labels the same as their names (they can be different):

  - `app: ubuntu`
  - `app: ubuntu-additional`
- Kubernetes cluster version `1.18.X`

> *Why do I specify Kubernetes version?*
>
> > Kubernetes 1.16 will remove the duplicate `pod_name` and `container_name` metric labels from cAdvisor metrics. For the 1.14 and 1.15 release all `pod`, `pod_name`, `container` and `container_name` were available as a grace period.
>
> - *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Metrics Overhaul](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1206)*

This means that you will need to substitute the parameters like:

- `pod` with `pod_name`
- `container` with `container_name`

To deploy Prometheus and other tools to monitor the cluster I used: *[Github.com: Coreos: Kube-prometheus](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus)*

The pods in `ubuntu` deployment are configured to generate artificial load (`stress-ng`). This is done to show how to avoid situation where the used resources are doubled.

The resources used by pods in `memory-testing` namespace:

```sh
$ kubectl top pod --namespace=memory-testing
NAME                                 CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
ubuntu-5b5d6c56f6-cfr9g              816m         280Mi           
ubuntu-5b5d6c56f6-g6vh9              834m         278Mi            
ubuntu-5b5d6c56f6-sxldj              918m         288Mi           
ubuntu-additional-84bdf9b7fb-b9pxm   0m           0Mi             
ubuntu-additional-84bdf9b7fb-dzt72   0m           0Mi             
ubuntu-additional-84bdf9b7fb-k5z6w   0m           0Mi
```

If you were to query Prometheus with below query:

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="memory-testing", pod=~"ubuntu.*"}
```

You would get output similar to one below (it's cut to show only one pod for example purposes, by default it would show all pods with `ubuntu` in name and in `memory-testing` namespace):

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{endpoint="https-metrics",id="/kubepods/besteffort/podb96dea39-b388-471e-a789-8c74b1670c74",instance="192.168.0.117:10250",job="kubelet",metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor",namespace="memory-testing",node="node1",pod="ubuntu-5b5d6c56f6-cfr9g",service="kubelet"} 308559872
container_memory_usage_bytes{container="POD",endpoint="https-metrics",id="/kubepods/besteffort/podb96dea39-b388-471e-a789-8c74b1670c74/312980f90e6104d021c12c376e83fe2bfc524faa4d4cee6553182d0fa2e007a1",image="k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2",instance="192.168.0.117:10250",job="kubelet",metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor",name="k8s_POD_ubuntu-5b5d6c56f6-cfr9g_memory-testing_b96dea39-b388-471e-a789-8c74b1670c74_0",namespace="memory-testing",node="node1",pod="ubuntu-5b5d6c56f6-cfr9g",service="kubelet"} 782336
container_memory_usage_bytes{container="ubuntu",endpoint="https-metrics",id="/kubepods/besteffort/podb96dea39-b388-471e-a789-8c74b1670c74/1b93889a3e7415ad3fa040daf89f3f6bc77e569d85069de518267666ede8e21c",image="ubuntu@sha256:55cd38b70425947db71112eb5dddfa3aa3e3ce307754a3df2269069d2278ce47",instance="192.168.0.117:10250",job="kubelet",metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor",name="k8s_ubuntu_ubuntu-5b5d6c56f6-cfr9g_memory-testing_b96dea39-b388-471e-a789-8c74b1670c74_0",namespace="memory-testing",node="node1",pod="ubuntu-5b5d6c56f6-cfr9g",service="kubelet"} 307777536
```

In this point you will need to choose which metric you will be using. In this example I used the first one. For more of a deep dive please take a look on this articles:

- *[Blog.freshtracks.io: A deep dive into kubernetes metrics part 3 container resource metrics](https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-3-container-resource-metrics-361c5ee46e66)*
- *[Ianlewis.org: Almighty pause container](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/almighty-pause-container)*

If we were to aggregate this metrics with `sum (QUERY) by (pod)` we would have in fact doubled our reported used resources.

**Dissecting the main query:**

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="memory-testing", container=""}
```

Above query will output records with used memory metric for each pod. The `container=""`parameter is used to get only one record (mentioned before) which does not have `container` parameter.

```
kube_pod_labels{label_app=~"ubuntu.*"}
```

Above query will output record with pods and it's labels with regexp of `ubuntu.*`

```
kube_pod_labels{label_app=~"ubuntu.*"} * on (pod) group_right(label_app) container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="memory-testing", container=""}
```

Above query will match the `pod` from `kube_pod_labels` with `pod` of `container_memory_usage_bytes` and add the `label_app` to each of the records.

```
sum (kube_pod_labels{label_app=~"ubuntu.*"} * on (pod) group_right(label_app) container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="memory-testing", container=""}) by (label_app)
```

Above query will sum the records by `label_app`.

After that you should be able to get the query that will sum the used memory by a label (and in fact a Deployment).

[image: Grafana Prometheus query]

---

As for:

> The same I'd like to achieve with the metric
> `kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes`.

You can use below query to get the memory limit for the deployment tagged with labels as in previous example, assuming that each pod in a deployment is having the same limits:

```
kube_pod_labels{label_app="ubuntu-with-limits"} * on (pod) group_right(label_app) kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes{namespace="memory-testing", pod=~".*"}
```

You can apply functions like `avg()`,`mean()`,`max()` on this query to get the single number that will be your memory limit:

```
avg(kube_pod_labels{label_app="ubuntu-with-limits"} * on (pod) group_right(label_app) kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes{namespace="memory-testing", pod=~".*"}) by (label_app)
```

Your memory limits  can vary if you use `VPA`. In that situation you could show all of them simultaneously or use the `avg()` to get the average for all of the "deployment".

[image: Combined resources and limits]

---

As a **workaround** to above solutions you could try to work with regexp like below:

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{pod=~"^ubuntu-.{6,10}-.{5}"}
```

Comment: This was very great. Thank you. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The following PromQL query should return per-deployment memory usage in Kubernetes:

```
sum(
  label_replace(
    container_memory_usage_bytes{pod!=""},
    "deployment", "$1", "pod", "(.+)-[^-]+-[^-]+"
  )
) by (namespace,deployment)
```

The query works in the following way:

1. The `container_memory_usage_bytes{pod!=""}` [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) selects all the time series with the name `container_memory_usage_bytes` and with non-empty `pod` label. We need to filter out time series without `pod` label, since such time series account for [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) hierarchy, which isn't needed in this query. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328) for more details on this.
2. The inner [label_replace()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) extracts deployment name from `pod` label and puts it to `deployment` label. It expects that pod names are constructed with the following pattern: `<deployment>-<some_suffix_1>-<some_suffix_2>`.
3. The outer [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) sums pod memory usage per each group with identical `namespace` and `deployment` labels.