# PromQL - get the number of pods running in a deployment

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I have two deployments running on the same namespace.
For the sake of the question let's call them "bob" and "bob-worker", both running in namespace "bob".
Each such deployment has an HPA attached to it, auto-scaling it.

I want to graph by time the number of pods running per deployment (so that would be two graphs).
I just can't seem to find any working solution. All solutions are per namespace instead of per deployment.

Comment: Maybe this will give you a hint on how you can get pods in a deployment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677636/container-memory-usage-bytes-by-deployment-name/63018741#63018741

Comment: https://sysdig.com/blog/prometheus-query-examples/

Comment: these do not help me. "bob" and "bob-worker" both trigger the same regex.
I am starting to see the answer is "rename stuff so that prometheus will tell the difference"

It is SO STRANGE that pods are not sorted by deployment...